# Redirect by string/keyword referer .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer

Im trying to redirect users by keyword or string using this .htaccess but it seems to be redirecting all users regardless if it contains the keyword or not. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?keyword(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?key\+word(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?key%20word(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} keyword [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} key\+word [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} key%20word [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^.* http://myurl.com [R=301,L]
```

also rewrite condition to block hosts whos rDNS did not resolve. The hostname is the exact same as IP. This is a bad bot footprint i'm trying to eliminate but it seems to be catching and host if it contains an IP address.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.+?)::\1$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}::%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.+?)::\1$ [OR]
```

Logs

```
5/20/2014 01:51 PM | UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; en-us; KFAPWI Build/JDQ39)
AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Silk/3.17 Safari/535.19 Silk-Accelerated=true| 
IP: 207.86.30.98   HOST: 207.86.30.98 |
```

Comment: leave only one condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} key(\%20|\+)?word [NC]`

Comment: Still having the same result, It's redirecting all users still regardless if the Keyword exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `OR` flag at the end of your conditions. It makes mod_rewrite think a blank condition is enough to satisfy the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?keyword(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?key\+word(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?key%20word(-|.).*$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} keyword [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} key\+word [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} key%20word [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://myurl.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: wouldn't that mean it would have to meet ALL conditions instead of just 1? That referer string would have to contain all variations? Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @affiliatex The `OR` flag means, [**or** next condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), so because there was an `OR` in your last condition, it meant "any of the 6 conditions *or* blank", and for whatever reason, "blank" is always true, thus the conditions were always satisfied.

Comment: OH!! I totally misread that so [OR] at the END of the conditions. Ok, testing now

Comment: Ok that seems to be working on a live traffic source. I also found another error I had in my .htaccess. I was using this line to filter out Hosts whos rDNS does not resolve. (see above edit)